# store.push not reflecting on template with ember-cli-pagination

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to add an object to the store after an ajax request.

**The problem** is that it does not reflect on template if I use **ember-cli-pagination**.

If I use `this.store.findAll` in model, it works, but when I use `this.findPaged` it does not.

I'm using **ember-inspector** and the object appears in the store, just don't in the browser.

My code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RouteMixin from 'ember-cli-pagination/remote/route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(RouteMixin, {
  actions: {
    create: function(email) {
      let adapter = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('adapter:application');
      let url = adapter.buildURL('billing/delivery-files');
      let store = this.get('store');
      let modelName = 'billing/delivery-file';

      return adapter.ajax(url, 'POST', {
        email: email
      }).then(function(data) {
        var normalized = store.normalize(modelName, data.object);
        store.push(normalized);
      });
    }
  },
  model(params) {
    return this.findPaged('billing/delivery-file',params); //does not work
    // return this.store.findAll('billing/delivery-file'); //works
  }
});
```

Tried the solutions from this [issue](https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination/issues/89), and did not work at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out!

After pushing to the store, I needed to push to the paginated array a reference to the store object. Don't know exactly why but it worked like a charm!

`model.content.pushObject(pushedRecord._internalModel);`

In my case I wanted it at the first position of the array, so I did:

`model.content.insertAt(0, pushedRecord._internalModel);`